# check if ng bootstrap modal is already open

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

How can I check that a modal window is open ?

I define a property like this

```
  modalInstance: NgbModalRef;
```

and instantiate the modal like this

```
 this.modalInstance = this.modalService.open(UpdateModalContent);
```

I can't find any native property like `this.modalReminderInstance.isOpen`

Comment: why don't you just set a variable when you open the modal and check this variable to find out if it is open or not? saves faffing about

Answer (score 7):

When you setup the `modalInstance` it returns a promise, while the modal is up that promise is set to `pending`, when the modal is closed the promise status will be set to either resolved or rejected.
When a promise will resolve/reject one of it's handlers in the `.then` method will run.

```
var isModalOpen = false;
function openModal() {
    isModalOpen = true;
    modalInstance = $uibModal.open({...})
        .result.then(function () {
            // do something when resolved
        });
}
```

Another way is to utilize the callback methods `.open` provides you

> The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:
>
> opened (Type: promise) - Is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables.
>
> closed (Type: promise) - Is resolved when a modal is closed and the animation completes.

```
var isModalOpen = false;

function openModal() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({...});

    modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
            isModalOpen = true;
        });

    modalInstance.closed.then(function () {
            isModalOpen = false;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, since you are using the modal service

```
this.modalInstance = this.modalService.open(UpdateModalContent)
```

you could use the "hasOpenModals" provided by the NgbModal class:

```
if (!this.modalService.hasOpenModals()) {
this.modalInstance = this.modalService.open(UpdateModalContent)
}
```